# Variable scope using VB in MS Access

Tags: function, ms-access, scope, vba

I have not used VB much but as far as I can tell scope works the same as in C#. The problem is, I'm using VB in MS Access so I am unsure if the rules are a bit different (though I assume they are not). The following code shows values being assigned to variables which have only been declared within the function parameters. Specifically looking at PurchaseOrderID, I am unsure as to how it is retaining its assigned value for use in the function proceeding it.

```
Function Create(SupplierID As Long, EmployeeID As Long, OrderID As Long, PurchaseOrderID As Long) As Boolean
    Dim rsw As New RecordsetWrapper
    If rsw.OpenRecordset("Purchase Orders") Then
        With rsw.Recordset
            .AddNew
            ![Supplier ID] = SupplierID
            If EmployeeID > 0 Then
                ![Created By] = EmployeeID
                ![Creation Date] = Now()
                ![Submitted By] = EmployeeID
                ![Submitted Date] = Now()
                ![Status ID] = Submitted_PurchaseOrder
            End If

            If OrderID > 0 Then
                ![Notes] = InsertString(PurchaseGeneratedBasedOnOrder, CStr(OrderID))
            End If
            If rsw.Update Then
                .Bookmark = .LastModified
                PurchaseOrderID = ![Purchase Order ID]
                Create = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function


Function CreateLineItem(PurchaseOrderID As Long, ProductID As Long, UnitCost As Long, Quantity As Long) As Boolean
    Dim rsw As New RecordsetWrapper
    If rsw.OpenRecordset("Purchase Order Details") Then
        With rsw.Recordset
            .AddNew
            ![Purchase Order ID] = PurchaseOrderID
            ![Product ID] = ProductID
            ![Quantity] = Quantity
            ![Unit Cost] = UnitCost
            CreateLineItem = rsw.Update
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Can someone give me some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to a VBA procedure by value or by reference.  If you don't specify either `ByVal` or `ByRef` in the procedure's declaration, it defaults to `ByRef`.  So the following two declarations are equivalent ...

```
Function DoSomething(PurchaseOrderID As Long) AS Boolean
Function DoSomething(ByRef PurchaseOrderID As Long) AS Boolean
```

The key here is that `ByRef` allows changes to the argument within the procedure to be transmitted back to the caller.

Comment: I thought Long was immutable i.e only passed by value?

Comment: In VBA/VB6, procedure arguments of any type are passed by reference unless qualified as `ByVal`.

Comment: @Nate Check out the Access help topic for the ByRef keyword and Function Statement.

Comment: @David It would explain how this code seems to run without error. Do you know if this is this also true for newer versions of VB?

Comment: @HansUp Thanks, you're answer basically answers my query fully.

Comment: In VB.NET, the default is the same as C#, passing by value unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @David Thanks. I have to say I am not liking VB much. It feels less intuitive that the other languages I'm familiar with. I just felt like expressing that opinion to someone :)

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, how you call a procedure can be important.

> "Even if a called procedure has declared its parameters as ByRef, you
>   can force those to be ByVal by enclosing each argument within
>   parentheses."

-- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

This is true of VBA in all Office applications. For example, let us say you have two procedures:

```
Sub SubByVal(ByVal Total As Integer)
    Total = 50
End Sub

Sub SubByRef(ByRef Total As Integer)
    Total = 50
End Sub
```

And you run a few tests:

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = 100
```

These three versions work as expected and Total is equal to 100

```
Call SubByVal(Total)
SubByVal (Total)
SubByVal Total
```

These two work as expected and Total is equal to 50

```
Call SubByRef(Total)
SubByRef Total
```

However, in this version, in spite of calling ByRef, Total is equal to 100, because it is forced to ByVal by the parentheses.

```
SubByRef (Total)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is best handled by types. Something like this:

```
Type PurchaseSet
   PurchaseOrderID As Long
   OrderCreated as boolean
End Type


Function Create(SupplierID As Long, EmployeeID As Long, OrderID As Long ) As PurchaseSet
    Dim rsw As New RecordsetWrapper
    Dim ps as PurchaseSet 
   ps.OrderCreated = false

    If rsw.OpenRecordset("Purchase Orders") Then
        With rsw.Recordset
            .AddNew
            ![Supplier ID] = SupplierID
            If EmployeeID > 0 Then
                ![Created By] = EmployeeID
                ![Creation Date] = Now()
                ![Submitted By] = EmployeeID
                ![Submitted Date] = Now()
                ![Status ID] = Submitted_PurchaseOrder
            End If

            If OrderID > 0 Then
                ![Notes] = InsertString(PurchaseGeneratedBasedOnOrder, CStr(OrderID))
            End If
            If rsw.Update Then
                .Bookmark = .LastModified
                ps.PurchaseOrderID = ![Purchase Order ID]
                ps.OrderCreated = True

            End If
        End With
    End If

    Create = ps
End Function
```